# probabilty of a point inside a non-convex polygon such that all rays coming from that point combinedly hit all sides of the polygon

Tags: algorithm, math, geometry

[like in this image rays coming from point P cannot hit side AE directly so point p does not satisfy the condition](https://i.stack.imgur.com/wNDNF.png) probability of a point inside a non-convex polygon such that all rays coming from that point combinedly hits all sides of the polygon.

If polygon is convex than i think that rays coming from any point inside the polygon combinedly will hit all sides .
I am interested in knowing for concave polygon case.
**We are given coordinates of vertex of the polygon.**

Comment: It is not clear - knowing what?

Comment: "all rays coming from that point hit all sides of the polygon" is not even satisfied by a convex polygon.  *Each* ray hits at most one side in a convex polygon (except possibly at endpoints of edges), and I'm pretty sure that *each* ray misses at least one side in a non-convex polygon.

Comment: i mean that all rays coming from a point combined hits all the sides.

Comment: Your question isn't clear. You can draw a circle, centered at the point, that surrounds the entire polygon. You can draw line segments to every point on that circle. In order to hit every point on that circle, you must also touch every point inside the circle, which means that every side of the polygon will have been touched.

Comment: @JimMischel http://i.stack.imgur.com/wNDNF.png like in this image ray coming from point P does not hit side AE directly.So P does not satisfy the condition.

Comment: For a convex polygon, you can cast a ray from any point inside the polygon to directly contact any side. That's not true for a convex polygon. You can construct a convex polygon such that there is no point that has line-of-sight access to every side.

Comment: @JimMischel can you please give an example

Comment: @MBo we know the coordinates of the vertex of polygon

Comment: And what do you want to know - find visibility kernel ?

Comment: So what is your question? Are you asking for the probability of a random point in a non-convex polygon meeting your conditions? The *possibility*? What exactly are you trying to determine?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The set of points from which you reach all edges of a polygon is called its visibility kernel.

The kernel is the intersection of the half planes on the left of all edges. For a simple polygon, it can be computed in linear time O(N).

If the points are drawn uniformly inside the polygon, the probability is the ratio of the area of the kernel to that of the polygon. The kernel can be empty, hence the probability zero. Only for convex polygons is it one.

Comment: can you tell me more about the algorithm for finding area of kernel for simple poylgon

Comment: @Baadshahshah Google it.

Answer (score 0):

For a convex polygon, you can cast rays from any point inside the polygon to intersect all of the edges.

For any non-convex polygon, there will be at least one point from which an edge will block the line of sight to another edge. And you can easily create a non-convex polygon in which *no* point has line of sight to all edges.

An example of the latter:

[image]

Comment: Does that answer the question ?

Comment: @YvesDaoust: I don't know. Partially, at least, as it provides an answer to the obliquely-asked question of the non-convex polygon in the OP's last paragraph.

Comment: The question is about a probability.